# Votes cast tally changing sporadically

Tags: support, status-bydesign, profile-page, voting, vote-count

A few hours ago (technically "yesterday" by SO time), I looked at my profile and noticed that I had voted on approximately 560 questions. Neat.

Later I realized there's a badge once you vote on 600 questions! Awesome!

So I voted up a couple more questions that I liked (and down one that I didn't). I checked my profile again just now, and it shows that I've voted on a total of 525 questions. Huh?

Is the system just toying with me because I want a badge now? My guess is no (though it would be funny if that were the case). If anyone can solve this mystery, I'd love to know what happened. Thanks.

Comment: Based on what you've said, I suspect it was probably the vote fraud script.

Comment: `DisplayedTally = RealTally + rand() * 100 - 50;`

Comment: This is due to not including deleted content (you downvoted a lot of questions that ended up being deleted later) in the vote totals on the profile...we're going to take a look at this and see if it makes sense to change the behavior there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running some quick numbers, I see that 33 questions that you downvoted (*at some point*, not necessarily recently) were deleted *in the last 2 days*...this accounts for the large flux in your numbers.

In the case of down votes on later-deleted questions (up votes as well, but for obvious reasons down+later deleted is more common), you'll see some fluctuation in the totals since the totals **do not** include votes on deleted posts.

This is intentional, and [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Answer (score 0):

Strange .. I don't see any indication that the voting anomaly script was ever triggered by your account.

Are you *sure* the count was higher on a previous day?

Comment: Positive. It was over 560 when I checked, which is why I noticed the badge for 600 votes. I figured I was only a few days away. Now it's 531 and I have probably voted on 6 questions since I posted this question. I should mention, I sometimes vote down ridiculous questions that I also vote to close, so maybe those were subsequently deleted. Still, 35 votes different is a lot.

Comment: @peng not sure, but votes on posts that are deleted would not be shown there. If you vote down a lot of bad questions that get deleted, that is possible.. at least in theory.

Comment: I vote down maybe 2-4 on an active day, often 0-1. If there was a vote recalc or something, that makes sense. Not a big deal, but I'll update this question if I notice this again.

Comment: @PengOne - In this case 33 questions that you downvoted were deleted in the last 2 days, accounts for the large fluctuation...we'll see if it makes sense to change how the counts behave with this in mind and update the answers here.

Comment: @Nick: Thanks for the explanation. It's such a minor thing, that I doubt it's worth tweaking, especially now that I understand the reason.